# Unable to clear TriggerListeners using Quartz 2.2.0 version

Tags: java, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

There is a requirement to upgrade the QUARTZ(org.quartz-scheduler) version from 1.8.6
to 2.2.0. 
For the code..,

```
cronTriggerBean.clearAllTriggerListeners();
```

When the version of QUARTZ changed to 2.2.0 the above method call gives a compile time error, saying 
**CronTriggerBean** doesnt have **clearAllTriggerListeners()**. So my question is, are there any alternatives
which does the same functinality as of **clearAllTriggerListeners**?

Comment: Guys any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`ListenerManager#removeTriggerListenerMatcher`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/ListenerManager.html#removeTriggerListenerMatcher(java.lang.String,%20org.quartz.Matcher)) to achieve the same result by using a "catch-all" matcher.

Comment: Walen,it would be great if you can give me any example how can I achieve this.

Comment: Not really, sorry -- I just looked through the API for a 2.2.x method similar to the 1.8.x one you mentioned. If your question said "Can anybody tell me how to use this method?", you'd probably get a couple comments telling you to try using it yourself first and to come back with any errors you found, so... go ahead :)

Comment: Hello Walen. Thanks a lot for your suggestion and my apologies for a really long delayed response. Actually we had to revert the changes rather to go for the new changes. I mean to say is, the management doesn't wants us to go for higher versions of Quartz. And thanks again :)